# wordpressプラグインのsyntaxhighhighterでjavascriptを表示しようとする崩れる

Tags: javascript, wordpress

コードを[js][/js]で囲んで表示しようとするとブロックまみれになってしまいます。

```
<div>//String</div>
<div>var s = new String('taguti')</div>
<div>var s = 'taguti'//文字列リテラル→これでもメソッドが使える</div>
<div>console.log(s.length)</div>
<div>console.log(s.replace('ti','chi'))</div>
<div>console.log(s.substr(1, 3))</div>
```

#### 確認したこと

・htmlautoscript => 関係ない。
・function.phpにremovefileter() => これでもだめ
・プラグイン「TinyMCE Advanced」の無効化 => 関係ない
・function.phpにremove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );　=> 関係ない

Comment: 私は当該プラグインを使用していませんが、`div`で囲む必要がないのでは？

Comment: 質問の仕方が悪かったかもしれません。ブロックで囲んでない部分を「ビジュアルエディター」貼り付けます。→すると自動的にブロックで囲まれてしまうのです。何が原因なのかがわからず対処できません。

Comment: そういうことならそれはレイアウトのために変更されたのでは？ それが思うように正しく標示されないならスタイルシート(CSS)が正しく設定されていないとかでは？

Comment: たったいま解決しました。wordpressには自動変換されてしまうフィルターというものがそなわっているようです。

Comment: なるほど、門外漢が失礼しました。 自己解決された場合、それを回答としてご自身で回答下さい。

Comment: すいません結果を投稿するのがはやとちりでした。この話は全てが勘違いだったようです。一応解決しましたが、フィルターは無関係でした。

Comment: 回答は編集リンクから修正できます。

Comment: この場合はWPのフィルターというよりはTinyMCEがそうなってるって感じですね……

Answer (score 0):

#### 事象

wordpressの投稿画面に[ビジュアルエディター]と[テキストエディター]がある。
ここで[ビジュアルエディター]にjavascriptコードを貼り付け[テキストエディター]に切り替えると「改変」されてしまう。

#### 解決方法

javascriptコードを[テキストエディター]で先に貼り付ける。そしたらなぜか改変されない。
応急的な対策ですが解決方法はこれです。下記のようなフィルター設定はしていません。

#### 参考URL

自動整形のフィルターが関係していると思ったが関係がなかった。（関係はあるのかもしれないが因果関係を見つけられなかった）

WordPressの自動整形（ビジュアルエディタ含む）を無効にする方法
https://qiita.com/jyokyoku/items/c560b0d1eacc1df61620